# How do I wait for next-auth session before using useQuery()?

Tags: node.js, reactjs, next.js, react-query, next-auth

I have a NextJS project that uses NextAuth for session management and then React Query to retrieve data on the front-end.

However, with the current format (as seen below), useSession() will return `undefined` while it checks if the session is authenticated, and then this `undefined` is used in the reactQuery, which will itself return `undefined`. How can I make sure useQuery is only called after the session is successfully retrieved and includes the userID, which can then be passed to useQuery?

```
const AirdropsPage = () => {
  const { data: session } = useSession();

  const { isLoading, isError, data } = useQuery(["airdropsData"], () =>
    fetch(`/api/airdrops?id=${session?.user?.id}`).then((res) => res.json()) //id is undefined
  );

  return (
    {isLoading ? (
      <Loader />
    ) : data ? (
      <Table data={data.airdrops} columns={columns} />
    ) : null}
  );
};
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Generally, what you'd want is to add all things that you use in your queryFn as the queryKey. Then, you can disable the query when your dependencies are not ready yet:

```
const { data: session } = useSession();
const id = session?.user?.id

const { isLoading, isError, data } = useQuery(
  ["airdropsData", id],
  () =>
    fetch(`/api/airdrops?id=${id}`).then((res) => res.json())
  ),
  {
    enabled: !!id
  }
)
```

as soon as `useSession` returns the id, the query will enable and will start to fetch. This is [documented here](https://tanstack.com/query/v4/docs/guides/disabling-queries#lazy-queries).

Answer (score 0):

The issue was due to wrapping the Next.js getLayout property around the React Query provider in _app.tsx. The solution was to move these providers outside the wrapper, as seen below.

````
function MyApp({ Component, pageProps }: AppPropsWithLayout<{ session: Session; }>) {
    const getLayout = Component.getLayout || ((page: any) => page);

    return 
        <SessionProvider session={pageProps.session}>
            {getLayout(
                <>
                    <Header />
                    <Component {...pageProps} />
                </>
             )}
        </SessionProvider>
    );
}```
````